# How do i go about implementing this publish/subscribe use case with spring boot and RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, microservices, messaging

I am not sure this question is applicable here but I needed to ask anyway, I want to implement a publish/subscribe messaging system between micro-services using spring boot.

My problem is: Lets say micro-service **A** sends an event which another micro-service **B** has subscribed to, is it possible for Micro-service **B** to now use the event for whatever use case which might take as long as it needs and then publish a different event to which Micro-service **A** can now subscribe to, essentially can a micro-service act as both publisher and subscriber?

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: Is it good practice to build software this way?

Comment: "Good practice" is vague term. I personally did it and had no problem with it.

Comment: thanks. I was worried i was using a "hack" solution to my problem